# Does factory pattern create object only with default constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns, graph, factory-pattern

I need your help please 
I have a complex Network represented as hypergraph
Hypergraph vertices has various type :image,tag ....
i should create thousand of vertices
it will be hard to create it manually!
so i thought that factory pattern may help me in this case
but each vertex type has its specific proprieties that i should pass it as parameter to the constructor

so factory method is the right choice in this case?
[image: quick diagram]

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with a factory which has a create method which takes one or more parameters

```
Car blueCar = carFactory.create(CarColor.BLUE);
Car redCar = carFactory.create(CarColor.RED);
```

or a factory which has multiple create methods:

```
Car blueCar = carFactory.createBlueCar();
Car redCar = carFactory.createRedCar();
```

An alternative to the Factory which might also be worth considering depending on the use-case is the Builder pattern. A Builder has only one create method without parameters, but it also has methods which set the properties of the objects which will be created by it:

```
carBuilder.setColor(CarColor.BLUE);
Car blueCar = carBuilder.create();
carBuilder.setColor(CarColor.RED);
Car redCar = carBuilder.create();
```

How the create method actually creates the object internally is an implementation detail left to itself. It could, for example:

- Invoke a constructor with parameters
- Invoke a default constructor and then call some setters on the returned object to change its attributes
- Instantiate a different subclass depending on the parameters
- Or a combination of these options

Comment: it is possible to use both factory and builder pattern

Comment: @nawara Sure. When you want to, you can combine all three of the patterns above in one Creator object which sets some attributes through setters, has multiple create methods, and make some of the create methods require additional parameters. But if the resulting code is easy to read and to maintain is a different question.

Comment: i will try to apply those idea
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Factory method is usually used to create objects without the need of specifying the exact class of object that will be created.

If you have different implementations of vertices this may be your choice.

Comment: As it says in the GOF book: "Define an interface for creating an object, but let the classes that implement the interface decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses."